# How to handle business rules with a REST API?

Tags: api, web-services, rest, api-design, http

I have a REST API to manage a booking system
I'm searching how to manage this situation :

A customer can book a time slot :
A TimeSlot resource is created and linked to a Person resource. In order to create the link between a time lot and a person, the REST client send a POST request on the TimeSlot resource

But if too many people booked the same slot (let's say the limit is 5 links), it must be impossible to create more associations.

How can I handle this business restriction ? Can I return a 404 status code with a JSON response detailing the error with a status code ?

Is it a RESTFul approach ?

<s>**EDIT :**</s>

Like suggested below I used status 409 Conflict in addition to a JSON response detailing the error

**EDIT 2 :**

Like detailed in the @Cormac Mulhall, the 403 Forbidden is the most accurate status code for this case

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to you 403 Forbidden. From the HTTP specs

> 403 Forbidden: The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated.

You shouldn't use 409, it implies that the client might be able to resolve the conflict, which in the case of over booking the client can't do as the conflict rules are server side.

Remember in the context of HTTP status codes "conflict" means a conflict in the state of the resource (in this case the book time slot), <strike>for example it expects time in one format and you sent it in the wrong format</strike> [bad example, better one would be two clients update a resource at the same time and the server cannot figure out which update to save, like on a version controlled system]. The resource is a time slot, if you change to a different time slot you have created a different resource, not resolved a conflict with this resource.

> 409 Conflict: The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the resource. This code is **only allowed in
>   situations where it is expected that the user might be able to resolve
>   the conflict and resubmit the request.**

The server should return 403 Forbidden with an explanation that it is refusing to save the state because that time slot is already full. Nothing the client can do in altering the state of the resource can change that. The client should not re-submit. They must instead create a new time slot instead (you could return the closest free slot as a suggestion).

Comment: I think this should be the Answer to the question.

Comment: If the resource expects time in one format and you sent it in the wrong format, that'd be a 400 Bad Request, not 409 Conflict. 403 Forbidden is usually used in the case of permissions errors (you're logged-in but you're not entitled to modify the resource). 409 Conflict is appropriate here - the user _can_ resolve the conflict by picking a different time.

Comment: That is not the conflict 409 is talking about. It is talking about conflict in the state of the resource, not a general business rule conflict. An example of 409 would be two clients updating the resource at the same time and the server cannot figure out which diff to save. Here we have a larger business rule conflict where the client is trying to do something that fails the business rules on the server. Nothing the client can do will fix the TimeSlot resource, the server is flat out rejecting it. They must create a new, different resource, not fix a conflict with the current one.

Comment: You are right that time format is a bad example of 409, I've updated post to reflect.

Answer (score 4):

404 indicates a resource is not found. A more appropriate response code would be a [409](http://httpstatus.es/409) with a body containing more details if the nature of the conflict.

Answer (score 1):

**Attention** : See the Answer by Cormac Mullhall

404 means resource not found. Using it here would be not appropriate. Because the resource clearly exists, but cannot be manipulated. According to Quick Tips (http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restquicktips.html) <strike>409 Conflict would be a good way to go. You can of course return 200 with error message in the body. The client is still responsible for reading responses and act on them.</strike>

Comment: -1 for "You can of course return 200 with error message in the body." That's not the REST way!